# How to use Pow trait? Can you Pow<i32, Output=i32> with num crate?

Tags: rust

I want my function to accept i32 as T.

It throws: the trait `Pow<i32>` is not implemented for `i32`

help: the following implementations were found:
`<&'a i32 as Pow<u16>>`
`<&'a i32 as Pow<u32>>`
`<&'a i32 as Pow<u8>>`
`<&'a i32 as Pow<usize>>`
and 240 others

I am completly lost...

```
use num::{traits::Pow, Num};

pub const ADD: &str = "+";
pub const SUB: &str = "-";
pub const MUL: &str = "*";
pub const DIV: &str = "/";
pub const MOD: &str = "%";
pub const POW: &str = "^";

fn main() {
    calculate_operation(POW, 12_i32, 2_i32);
}

fn calculate_operation<T>(operation: &str, n1: T, n2: T) -> T
where
    T: Num + Pow<T, Output = T>,
{
    return match operation {
        ADD => n1 + n2,
        SUB => n1 - n2,
        MUL => n1 * n2,
        DIV => n1 / n2,
        POW => n1.pow(
            n2, /*.try_into()
               .expect("Failed to convert exponent in power operation.")*/
        ),
        MOD => n1 % n2,
        _ => panic!("{}: not a valid operation!", operation),
    };
}
```

Comment: Simply put, you cannot raise an integer to a *signed* integer power, as the latter might be negative. Integers may only be raised to an unsigned int (i.e., nonnegative) power.

Comment: @BallpointBen How could I change generics around to accomodate for that?

Comment: The best way is probably to create an enum with the operations where each variant holds its own operands.

Answer (score 0):

`i32` cannot be raised to the power of `i32` and result in `i32`, because `i32` might be negative and the result will not be a whole number. This is reflected by the fact that the `Pow` trait is not implemented for `i32` with `i32` as the generic parameter.

You can create a trait that will allow you to represent "the same bit width number type that can be used as an exponent for T", e.g.:

```rust
trait PowExponent: Sized
where
    Self: Pow<Self::Exponent, Output = Self>,
    Self::Exponent: TryFrom<Self>,
{
    type Exponent;
}

impl PowExponent for i32 {
    type Exponent = u32;
}
impl PowExponent for u32 {
    type Exponent = u32;
}
impl PowExponent for f32 {
    type Exponent = f32;
}
// Etc.

fn calculate_operation<T>(operation: &str, n1: T, n2: T) -> T
where
    T: Num + PowExponent,
{
    match operation {
        ADD => n1 + n2,
        SUB => n1 - n2,
        MUL => n1 * n2,
        DIV => n1 / n2,
        POW => n1.pow(n2.try_into().ok().unwrap("negative exponent")),
        MOD => n1 % n2,
        _ => panic!("{}: not a valid operation!", operation),
    }
}
```

However, the entire design of using a generic argument looks incorrect. Don't you know the type ahead of time?